# segmentation fault in unions with compiler optimization

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return

My code uses a union to represent an RGB pixel. It works well in debug mode, but with compiler optimizations enabled, it segfaults.

You can see below simplified test code to reproduce the error. My system is Ubuntu with GCC4.8.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

union Pixel {
    uint32_t color;
    uint8_t at[4];
};

typedef struct Screen {
    union Pixel *pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
    int rPosition;
    int gPosition;
    int bPosition;
} *Screen;

Screen ScreenCreate(int width, int height, uint32_t rPosition, uint32_t gPosition, uint32_t bPosition) {
    Screen this = malloc(sizeof *this);
    this->pixels = malloc(width * height * sizeof this->pixels[0]);
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->rPosition = rPosition;
    this->gPosition = gPosition;
    this->bPosition = bPosition;
}

void ScreenDelete(Screen this) {
    free(this->pixels);
    free(this);
}

void ScreenFill(Screen this, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
    union Pixel pixel;
    pixel.color = 0;
    pixel.at[this->rPosition] = r;
    pixel.at[this->gPosition] = g;
    pixel.at[this->bPosition] = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->width * this->height; i += 1) {
        this->pixels[i].color = pixel.color;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Screen screen = ScreenCreate(500, 500, 2, 1, 0);
    ScreenFill(screen, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
    ScreenDelete(screen);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend using C++ keywords (like `this`) in C code (in particular inside header files).

Comment: `typedef struct Screen *Screen;`, that is *really confusing*. Preferably do not use pointer typedefs at all; but if you must, then please give them a different name than the name of the type they are pointing to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `ScreenCreate()` function, you forgot a `return` statement. So, your code produces undefined behavior.

The last line should be

```
 return this;
```

Related: As per `C11` standard, chapter §6.9.1, Function definitions, paragraph 12

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

so, using the `screen` in `main()` causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Moral of the story: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.

Comment: @xiver77 because it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: And I am quite sure that if you did compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, the compiler would have warned you.

Comment: @xiver77 Undefined behaviour can include working as expected.